# Microsoft Visual Studio XAML UI Designer FileNotFoundException when Editing View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using WPF with .NET 4.5.2 on Visual Studio 2012 and getting a FileNotFoundException in the XAML view when editing my View:

[image]

The application compiles and runs fine otherwise. The exception manifests as a blue underline only.

I debugged XDesProc.exe and found this to be the source of the exception. The reason being that its working directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` so its looking for the config in the wrong place.

It occured to me that this might be a problem of design in the application. The exception is being thrown from in MainWindowViewModel.cs on this line:

`RemotingConfiguration.Configure("ZZZZZ.exe.config", false);`

I believe this line is being reached when the XAML UI Designer reaches this section of my View.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Which is where I'm instantiating my ViewModel and assigning it to the DataContext.

I think I need to move `RemotingConfiguration.Configure()` outside of my ViewModel constructor but I don't know where to put it. I believe this to be the solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use a screen capture, right click and save the actual error text to the posting please.

Comment: @OmegaMan I understand that text is preferred but the text in my case appears in a tooltip which I can't right click on. I also wanted to demonstrate how the exception manifests as an underline in source rather than an error window like one would expect.

Comment: Understood, as an aside, note that most model pop up boxes in window apps can have their text copied by highlighting the box and selecting CTRL-C. Its an old testers trick to get text from an error dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In design mode controls and instances which are specified in the xaml are instantiated. Within your VM (or other areas) there may be code which should not be attempted during design mode.

Its best to segregate out those sections by specifying whether or not to attempt it if it is design mode such as

```
if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) { ... } // if not in design mode.
```

---

Since the VM is the issue, here are the options.

- Instantiate the VM in code behind and when in design mode, don't instantiate it using the above logic check.
- If the VM *has to be instantiated* on the xaml for *religious* reasons then follow these steps.

  1. Name the VM in Xaml by adding the `Name` attribute on the VM in the Xaml.
  2. Create a Boolean (does not have to adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged`) on the VM named `IsInDesign`.
  3. In the main page  constructor check if in design mode using above logic and assign that value to the VM's `IsInDesign` to the named VM.
  4. In the constructor of the VM (which should instantiate after the Main page's constructor) check the value of `IsInDesign` and stop any loading/reading of files depending on its value.

Comment: This sounds promising but I get an error when I try to pass `this` to `GetIsInDesignMode()`: `Argument type '{Namespace}.MainWindowViewModel' is  not assignable to parameter type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'`

Comment: @KyleV right, I instantiated my VM on the codebehind of the main page and the `this` is that main page. If you can't create a VM in code behind. I suggest that you create a Boolean on your VM and do the assignment of it by the result while in the main page's constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by creating a boolean and assigning it the result? Can you give an example?